# MongoDB aggregation $unwind equivalent of ElasticSearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm pretty new to ElasticSearch, I recently indexed one of my MongoDB collection on ElasticSearch using compose transporter. The reason I indexed is I wanted to do full-text search on some of the fields.

So, now I have a nested document like below,

```
{  
  "item":"journal",
  "item_size":200,
  "instock":[  
  {  
     "warehouse":"A",
     "qty":5
  },
  {  
     "warehouse":"A",
     "qty":15
  }
 ]
}
```

If I want to do a MongoDB aggregate on the doc to match where warehouse is A and $unwind them,

> [{"$unwind":"$instock"},{"$match":{"instock.warehouse":"A"}}]

I'll get the following result,

```
{  
  "item":"journal",
  "item_size":200,
  "instock":  
  {  
     "warehouse":"A",
     "qty":5
  }
}


{  
  "item":"journal",
  "item_size":200,
  "instock":  
  {  
     "warehouse":"A",
     "qty":15
  }
}
```

This is just a simple example but I have more nested complex documents like this in MongoDB. How can I achieve the same result in the ElasticSearch?
I spent a lot of time figuring out this but no luck.

Comment: I think this topic explains a lot: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28836

Comment: @mickl, The discussion says they are not gonna implement this feature because it's hard to support such operations efficiently. Any workarounds?